# Session variables server side Vs. client side

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, jscript

I am setting the following in my Application_Error:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["ErrorMessage"] = "Error message for current user";
```

Then in my client side, I want to consume the error message and then clear this error. So I mistakenly thought I can do this:

```
$.session.remove('ErrorMessage');
```

But that doesn't do it. How can I clear the session variable? Thank you.

Comment: I've had to do something similar where I used AJAX to call a method in the controller to clear the session variable.  Maybe others have a simpler way of doing it but that's what I did.

Comment: did you try something @{Session["ErrorMessage"] = null; } or '@{Session["ErrorMessage"] = null; }';

Comment: Thanks @DougF, I hope there are other ways. Also Murat, yes, I have. I think this all tries to clear it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

When i use Razor in Javascript it work in that situation;

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            Session["Test"] = "Session Clean Test";
            return View();
        }
```

View side;

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#beforeClean').text('@Session["Test"]');
        });
        function CleanSession() {
            @{Session["Test"] = null;}
            $('#afterClean').text('@Session["Test"]');
        }
    </script>
}

<div class="row">
    <div id="beforeClean"> </div>
    <button id="session" type="button" onclick="CleanSession()">Clean Session</button>
    <div id="afterClean"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Murat. That's what I exactly did but no luck.

Comment: I am sorry that i couldn't help you. Then i am going to delete this answer which doesn't have to keep a place here :)

Comment: No worries. Thank you so much for trying.